# custom plugin assembly cannot be compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, iis-7, .net-assembly

I have a plugin written in C# for a web application. When it is called by the application, the plugin assembly cannot be compiled.

I have found the point of the problem, but IDNK how to solve it.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;

namespace App.plugins
{
    public class ThePlugin
    {
        public string ToHtml(){...}
    }
}
```

When I omit `using System.Linq;` the plugin is compiled successfully. I also checked the IIS for loaded assemblies and the `System.Core` (containing `System.Linq`) is in the list.

**EDIT:**

*How*:

```
 CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, SourceCode);
```

*Obtained*: error, that tells me in the System namespace name does not exist type or namespace Linq (Error No# CS0234)

*FrameWork*: `.NET FrameWork 4.5`

Any hints?

Comment: "The plugin assembly cannot be compiled" - so what goes wrong? What do you observe? How is the application compiling the plugin? What version of .NET are you using? *So* much information missing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to add `System.Core.dll` to the list of DLLs as below

```
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, SourceCode);
```